# The `class` keyword and User-Defined data types

Tags: c#, .net, oop

The title may be a bit weird. I don't know how to title this question in a better way.

Suddenly, I got extremely confused about data types. If a Class is a User-Defined data type, what does the keyword `class` do?

For example:

```
    internal class MyClass
    {
    }

    static class Main
    {

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        }

     }
```

So here, is the user-defined data type MyClass? If so, what does the keyword `class` do?

I thought `class` was just a blueprint for your user-defined data type. I'm not so sure anymore.

If you don't understand the question, please comment so I can maybe try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various categories of user-defined types - `class` is just one of them; see also:

- `struct`
- `enum`
- `delegate`
- `interface`

Here, `class` tells the compiler that you are defining a reference-type single-inheritance type.

Comment: So does the category also provide guidelines for the compiler? For example, if you define a data type which category is `enum`, the compiler knows not to allow methods in it.

Comment: @RoK basically, yes - although there is more to it than just whether methods are allowed - the entire syntax is different for enums and delegates; struct, class and interface have quite a lot of similarities though